# Bootstrapping bioequivalence results R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap, medical

I am trying to run a bootstrap simulation of a bioequivalence study in R with 3 pharmacokinetic parameters (AUC0-infinity [`AUCIFO`], AUClast [`AUCLST`], Cmax [`CMAX`]). I want to sample with replacement from the actual study dataset to increase the sample size from 25 to 100, perform the BE calculation (using the `bw2x2` function from the `BE` package), and then repeat that 1000 to 10000 times (depending on how long it takes to run) and generate a geometric mean ratio (GMR) for each parameter with 90%CI.

Here is a reprex dataset that I generated to represent the study date (sample size of 25):

```
require(dplyr)
require(BE)

set.seed(123)

aucifo_test <- rnorm(25, 2500, 25)
aucifo_ref <- rnorm(25, 2600, 25)
auclst_test <- rnorm(25, 2400, 25)
auclst_ref <- rnorm(25, 2400, 25)
cmax_test <- rnorm(25, 50, 5)
cmax_ref <- rnorm(25, 55, 5)

SUBJ = c(1:25)
GRP = sample(c(1,2), 25, replace = TRUE) 

be_df <- rbind(data.frame(SUBJ = SUBJ, GRP = GRP, TRT = "R", AUCIFO = aucifo_ref, AUCLST = auclst_ref, CMAX = cmax_ref),
            data.frame(SUBJ = SUBJ, GRP = GRP, TRT = "T",AUCIFO = aucifo_test, AUCLST = auclst_test, CMAX = cmax_test)) %>%
  mutate(PRD = case_when(
    GRP == 1 & TRT == "R" ~ 1,
    GRP == 1 & TRT == "T" ~ 2,
    GRP == 2 & TRT == "R" ~ 2,
    GRP == 2 & TRT == "T" ~ 1
  )) %>%
  mutate(GRP = case_when(
    GRP == 1 ~ "RT",
    GRP == 2 ~ "TR"
  )) %>%
  select(GRP, PRD, SUBJ, TRT, AUCIFO, AUCLST, CMAX)

be_results <- be2x2(be_df, c("AUCIFO", "AUCLST", "CMAX"))
```

The output of `be2x2` is a list, which can be subsetted by the column name to obtain the GMR. Here is the output of the BE results:

```
print(be_results)

$AUCIFO
$AUCIFO$`Analysis of Variance (log scale)`
                  Sum Sq Df   Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
SUBJECT        0.0024154 24 0.0001006   1.8132   0.07915 .  
GROUP          0.0001999  1 0.0001999   2.0749   0.16322    
SUBJECT(GROUP) 0.0022155 23 0.0000963   1.7355   0.09686 .  
PERIOD         0.0003246  1 0.0003246   5.8476   0.02392 *  
DRUG           0.0203062  1 0.0203062 365.8577 1.332e-15 ***
ERROR          0.0012766 23 0.0000555                       
TOTAL          0.0245614 49                                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

$AUCIFO$`Between and Within Subject Variability`
                                Between Subject Within Subject
Variance Estimate                  2.041146e-05    5.55029e-05
Coefficient of Variation, CV(%)    4.517928e-01    7.45013e-01

$AUCIFO$`Least Square Means (geometric mean)`
                Reference Drug Test Drug
Geometric Means       2601.982  2499.114

$AUCIFO$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`
                 Lower Limit Point Estimate Upper Limit
90% CI for Ratio   0.9570003      0.9604654   0.9639432

$AUCIFO$`Sample Size`
                      True Ratio=1 True Ratio=Point Estimate
80% Power Sample Size            2                         2


$AUCLST
$AUCLST$`Analysis of Variance (log scale)`
                  Sum Sq Df    Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
SUBJECT        0.0019802 24 0.00008251  0.9748 0.52554  
GROUP          0.0000025  1 0.00000248  0.0288 0.86668  
SUBJECT(GROUP) 0.0019778 23 0.00008599  1.0159 0.48504  
PERIOD         0.0003203  1 0.00032025  3.7837 0.06408 .
DRUG           0.0001160  1 0.00011600  1.3705 0.25371  
ERROR          0.0019467 23 0.00008464                  
TOTAL          0.0043485 49                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

$AUCLST$`Between and Within Subject Variability`
                                Between Subject Within Subject
Variance Estimate                  6.746561e-07   8.464061e-05
Coefficient of Variation, CV(%)    8.213747e-02   9.200228e-01

$AUCLST$`Least Square Means (geometric mean)`
                Reference Drug Test Drug
Geometric Means       2407.201  2399.873

$AUCLST$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`
                 Lower Limit Point Estimate Upper Limit
90% CI for Ratio    0.992516      0.9969559    1.001416

$AUCLST$`Sample Size`
                      True Ratio=1 True Ratio=Point Estimate
80% Power Sample Size            2                         2


$CMAX
$CMAX$`Analysis of Variance (log scale)`
                Sum Sq Df  Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
SUBJECT        0.17640 24 0.007350  0.6666 0.834823   
GROUP          0.00032  1 0.000321  0.0419 0.839670   
SUBJECT(GROUP) 0.17608 23 0.007656  0.6943 0.805917   
PERIOD         0.00308  1 0.003078  0.2792 0.602300   
DRUG           0.12204  1 0.122036 11.0680 0.002934 **
ERROR          0.25360 23 0.011026                    
TOTAL          0.55687 49                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

$CMAX$`Between and Within Subject Variability`
                                Between Subject Within Subject
Variance Estimate                             0     0.01102599
Coefficient of Variation, CV(%)               0    10.52948160

$CMAX$`Least Square Means (geometric mean)`
                Reference Drug Test Drug
Geometric Means       53.51791  48.47896

$CMAX$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`
                 Lower Limit Point Estimate Upper Limit
90% CI for Ratio   0.8608553      0.9058456   0.9531872

$CMAX$`Sample Size`
                      True Ratio=1 True Ratio=Point Estimate
80% Power Sample Size            3                         6
```

You can subset the results such that you isolate the GMR point estimate. For example if I want the point estimate for AUCIFO, I can enter `` be_results$AUCIFO$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`[2] ``.

I am trying to use the `bootstrap` package to run the bootstrapping itself. So far I have the following `theta` function:

```
theta <- function(x) {
  
  temp <- data.frame(SAMP = sample(c(1:25), 100, replace=TRUE), ID = c(1:100)) #get random sample of 100 subject IDs
  
  ref <- temp %>% left_join(., x %>% filter(TRT == "R"), by = c("SAMP" = "SUBJ")) %>% select(-SAMP) #join reference samples subject IDs with study data and replace ID with new value
  
  test <- temp %>% left_join(., x %>% filter(TRT == "T"), by = c("SAMP" = "SUBJ")) %>% select(-SAMP) #join test samples subject IDs with study data and replace ID with new value
  
  be_df <- rbind(ref,test) %>% rename(SUBJ=ID) #join test and reference into single dataset
  
  be_results <- be2x2(be_df, c("AUCIFO", "AUCLST", "CMAX"))
  AUCIFO_GMR <- c(be_results$AUCIFO$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`[2])
  AUCLST_GMR <- c(be_results$AUCLST$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`[2])
  CMAX_GMR <- c(be_results$CMAX$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`[2])
}
```

However, when I try to run the following (small `nboot` for troubleshooting): `bootstrap(be_df, 10, theta)`, I get the following error message: `Error in UseMethod("filter") :  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "list"`

I am thinking this has something to do with the fact that I am trying to use a dataframe in the `bootstrap` function. Any help is appreciated!

**Solution**

Thanks to @jay.sf for the helpful answer! Made some additional tweaks to the code to output a dataframe, which are below:

```
theta <- function() {
  
  temp <- data.frame(SAMP = sample(c(1:25), 100, replace=TRUE), ID = c(1:100)) #get random sample of 100 subject IDs
  
  ref <- temp %>% left_join(., x101_boot_be %>% filter(TRT == "R"), by = c("SAMP" = "SUBJ")) %>% select(-SAMP) #join reference samples subject IDs with study data and replace ID with new value
  
  test <- temp %>% left_join(., x101_boot_be %>% filter(TRT == "T"), by = c("SAMP" = "SUBJ")) %>% select(-SAMP) #join test samples subject IDs with study data and replace ID with new value
  
  be_df <- rbind(ref,test) %>% rename(SUBJ=ID) #join test and reference into single dataset
  
  be_results <- be2x2_quiet(be_df, c("AUCIFO", "AUCLST", "CMAX"))
  AUCIFO_GMR <- c(be_results$AUCIFO$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`[2])
  AUCLST_GMR <- c(be_results$AUCLST$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`[2])
  CMAX_GMR <- c(be_results$CMAX$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`[2])
  
  output = list(c(AUCIFO_GMR=AUCIFO_GMR, AUCLST_GMR=AUCLST_GMR, CMAX_GMR=CMAX_GMR))
  
  }

boostrap_results <- replicate(1000L, theta())

boostrap_results_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, boostrap_results))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `replicate` your bootstrap function you actually don't need the `boot` package; just re-write it a little.

```
theta1 <- function() {
  temp <- data.frame(SAMP= sample(c(1:25), 100, replace=TRUE), ID= c(1:100)) #get random sample of 100 subject IDs
  ref <- temp %>% left_join(., be_df %>% filter(TRT== "R"), by= c("SAMP"= "SUBJ")) %>% select(-SAMP) #join reference samples subject IDs with study data and replace ID with new value
  test <- temp %>% left_join(., be_df %>% filter(TRT== "T"), by= c("SAMP"= "SUBJ")) %>% select(-SAMP) #join test samples subject IDs with study data and replace ID with new value
  be_df <- rbind(ref, test) %>% rename(SUBJ=ID) #join test and reference into single dataset
  be_results <- be2x2_quiet(be_df, c("AUCIFO", "AUCLST", "CMAX"))
  AUCIFO_GMR <- c(be_results$AUCIFO$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`[2])
  AUCLST_GMR <- c(be_results$AUCLST$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`[2])
  CMAX_GMR <- c(be_results$CMAX$`90% Confidence Interval of Geometric Mean Ratio (T/R)`[2])
  c(AUCIFO_GMR, AUCLST_GMR, CMAX_GMR)
}

set.seed(42)
res <- replicate(299L, theta1())

matrixStats::rowQuantiles(res, probs=c(.025, .975))
#           2.5%     97.5%
# [1,] 0.9598403 0.9632898
# [2,] 0.9984093 1.0012312
# [3,] 0.8945873 0.9559859
```

You could also use the usual `apply(res, 1, quantile, probs=c(.025, .975))` but  `matrixStats::rowQuantiles` is > 50% faster.

---

And here is the referenced quiet version of `b2x2`:

```
be2x2_quiet <-  function (Data, Columns = c("AUClast", "Cmax", "Tmax"), rtfName = "", plot=FALSE) {
  if ("data.frame" %in% class(Data)) {
    bedata = Data
  }
  else if ("character" %in% class(Data)) {
    bedata = read.csv(Data)
  }
  else {
    stop("Data should be data.frame or file name!")
  }
  bedata = bedata[order(bedata$GRP, bedata$PRD, bedata$SUBJ), 
  ]
  if (!assert(bedata)) {
    cat("\n Subject count should be balanced!\n")
    return(NULL)
  }
  nCol = length(Columns)
  if (nCol == 0) 
    stop("Input Error. Please, check the arguments!")
  if (rtfName != "") {
    rtf = RTF(rtfName)
    addHeader(rtf, title = "Bioequivalence Test Result")
    addNewLine(rtf)
    addHeader(rtf, "Table of Contents")
    addTOC(rtf)
  }
  Result = vector()
  for (i in 1:nCol) {
    if (plot) {                    ## defaults to FALSE #######################
      plot2x2(bedata, Columns[i])
    }
    if (toupper(Columns[i]) != "TMAX") {
      cResult = test2x2(bedata, Columns[i])
    }
    else {
      cResult = hodges(bedata, Columns[i])
    }
    if (rtfName != "") {
      addPageBreak(rtf)
      addHeader(rtf, title = Columns[i], TOC.level = 1)
      LineResult = capture.output(print(cResult))
      for (j in 1:length(LineResult)) addParagraph(rtf, 
                                                   LineResult[j])
      addPageBreak(rtf)
      addPlot(rtf, plot.fun = plot2x2a, width = 6.5, height = 6.5, 
              res = 300, bedata = bedata, Var = Columns[i])
      addPageBreak(rtf)
      addPlot(rtf, plot.fun = plot2x2b, width = 6.5, height = 6.5, 
              res = 300, bedata = bedata, Var = Columns[i])
    }
    Result = c(Result, list(cResult))
  }
  if (rtfName != "") {
    addPageBreak(rtf)
    addSessionInfo(rtf)
    done(rtf)
  }
  names(Result) = Columns
  return(Result)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you specify what the "quiet" is referring to for the `be2x2_quiet` function?

Comment: @Adam Since it was cluttering my entire screen with 299*6 plot windows during bootstrap, I added a `plot=` argument as a cure. It is used in line 28 to activate the plot function just `if` desired. To still get the plots just do `be2x2_quiet(., plot=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Is there a way to return 3 vectors or a dataframe from `theta`? When I am running the code now, it just returns 1 vector, which I assume is the `CMAX_GMR` since it was the last value specified in the function. My function building skills are a bit weak, so apologies if it is a simple solution.

Comment: @Adam Your theta function looks great, you probably want `c(AUCIFO_GMR, AUCLST_GMR, CMAX_GMR)` as last line, see edit.